# Vue not updating when data changes.

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm getting a strange issue where when I change my data within my Vue instance, the HTML is not updating:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/martynball/pen/rqxZmO?)

HTML:

```
<div class="favourites-panel__wrapper" id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(vehicle, index) in vehicles">{{ vehicle.id }}</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" v-on:click="add()">Add</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.panel = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        vehicles: {}
    },
    created: function() {

        // Create dummy vehicles
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            this.vehicles[i] = this.dummy(i);
        }

    },
    methods: {
      add: function() {
        let index = Object.keys(this.vehicles).length;
        let dummy = this.dummy(index);

        this.vehicles[Object.keys(this.vehicles).length] = dummy;
      },
      dummy: function(i) {
        return {
          'dummy': true,
          'body': 'loading',
          'fuel_type': 'loading',
          'gearbox_type': 'loading',
          'id': 'loading' + i,
          'image': '/assets/images/themev2/compare-dummy.gif',
          'image_id': 'loading',
          'make': 'loading',
          'model': 'loading',
          'location_name': 'loading',
          'variant': 'loading',
          'web_price': 'loading'
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
Vue.set(this.vehicles, Object.keys(this.vehicles).length, dummy);
```

insted of

```
this.vehicles[Object.keys(this.vehicles).length] = dummy;
```

Comment: This seems to work, how come I need to use `Vue.set`, where in the documentation example I can just add an object as normal? Is it because my `vehicles` data is an object rather than a key? 
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the Vue.set(object, key, value) method: from official documentaion. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Caveats::
Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:

When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue
When you modify the length of the array, e.g. vm.items.length = newLength